# Wrong page is indexing for a specific keyword phrase on my site

Tags: seo, google-search

When you search for the keyword phrase "New Camaro Car," the page for "New Mustang Car" appears in the results instead of "New Camaro Car."

```
Page #1-
Page Title: New Camaro Car
URL: /new-camaro-car
H1: New Camaro Car
Page Content: Exact Phrase of "New Camaro Car" is used twice.
Search Result Ranking for "New Camaro Car" : not-indexing (for this search)


Page #2-
Title: New Mustang Car
URL: /new-mustang-car
H1: New Mustang Car
Page Content: Exact Phrase is used twice for "New Mustang Car." But zero times for "New Camaro Car"
Search Result Ranking for "New Camaro Car": #1
Search Result Ranking for "New Mustang Car": #9
```

Why is my "New Mustang Car" page indexing for the "New Camaro Car" search instead of my "New Camaro Car" page?

The "New Camaro Car" page is indexed, and does appear on Google for different searches. There are no Google Penalties, and no duplicate content issues. When you do an exact quote search; "New Camaro Car," the "New Mustang Car" page is still appearing at #1 result, even though the phrase is not used once on the page. (It is the only webpage on Google that comes up without having the exact quote on the page). On Bing everything works and both are appearing in the top 5 for their desired keyword phrases.

Any ideas of why this could be happening?

Comment: It is impossible for us to know. Not without a domain name and the exact search phrases. Sorry. Otherwise, we would be guessing. Google has made mistakes before. They are usually temporary. It could just be one of those senior moments.

Comment: Even when you search "camaro car," ...the "new mustang car" page still comes up.     I understand it's not ideal having example words, but surely this has had to happen before. Google should not be making this mistake, Bing didn't.  Any guesses based upon the information would be greatly helpful, Thanks.

Comment: A shot in the dark guess could be "Co-Occurrence" as in maybe Google is assuming it's a relative word to the query; http://www.seobythesea.com/2013/08/google-substitute-query-terms-co-occurrence/            Like what reason would Google have to think the Mustang page is more relevant for the Camaro page even though clearly it is not as far as the textual information on the page goes?

Comment: I gave you an up-vote. I am not sure I can guess. Hopefully your question will get some attention so that you get an answer. Cheers!!

Comment: Actually, that is likely not too off the mark. Semantics can weigh similar *things* as being within the same topic. Still, you would think that Google is smarter than that. As well, check for meta tags such as open graph and what not, outbound links, etc.

Comment: I know this sounds stupid, but check for broken HTML especially within templated HTML. Normally, this should not be a problem, however, I have seen some really weird errors as a result. Even with Google. But it has been a while.

Comment: I will check those thanks. The website is using wordpress and a template as well...     Another note that could tie to camaro:
This website was migrated from another website. The old website had "camaro" as part of the domain name. It changed from "coolcamaro.com" to "coolautomobiles.com"
Every page on coolcamaro.com has been 301 redirected to the coolautomobiles.com equivalent page. And actually, coolcamaro.com did not have a mustang page, but it did have the mustang page linked from it's header drop down menu.

Comment: *The old website had "camaro" as part of the domain name.* Ah Ha!! That is it! (I assume.) The domain name semantic term weight is the highest of all of the elements. I have seen Google turn up the volume knob on how domain names effect search this year or late last year. I bet the behavior will change if you were to drop the old domain name and go with the new one exclusively.

Comment: Are you suggesting to un-index the old domain name all together? It was migrated 6 months ago, and is not appearing on Google anyways because the 301 re-directs are all set-up.  I read that it's good to leave the old website indexed for Google as long as possible + using the Google Webmastertools Change of Address....    If I was to make this un-index, can i still leave my 301 re-directs?

Comment: Yes and No. I always suggest leaving the old domain for as long as it makes sense. I also always advise creating an inbound link profile greater than the old website (over time) because, it always seems to be, that at some point it makes sense to drop the old domain. It is better for new links to go to the new domain at some point. You may want to think about trading the 301 for a CNAME and using canonical tags pointing to the new domain. That might work! It would be good to hear what others think. Cheers!!

Comment: I wonder if your inbound links could be affecting this? Have you checked backlinks to see if you have a lot of links from Camaro-focused websites?